# better git commit template in intellij

Tags: git, intellij-idea

When committing from the shell, it loads vi and has the following information:

```
# Please enter the commit message for your changes. Lines starting
# with '#' will be ignored, and an empty message aborts the commit.
# On branch develop
# Changes to be committed:
#   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
# ......
```

And then lists the contents of `git status`.  I like these more detailed commit bodies but when I commit via intellij's interface, this is lost.  I can't seem to determine if its possible to tell intellij to include this information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please note that this body is not committed to Git. Anything that starts with a hash when you commit from vi is considered a comment and is not included to the commit message. Only the text that you write is included. From this point of view, IntelliJ doesn't differ from vi.

As per commit message templates, they are not supported by now: [IDEA-66355](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-66355)